# how to refer a textbox inside body of html page in a javascript if textbox is not part of any form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, refer

i have coded a header file which contains a input textbox for search.this header is include in body tag of  a jsp page as shown below.

```
<body>
<include src="header.ssi">
<form>
</form>
```

onclick of button i header file i am running a javascript function.
i need to refer to this textbox in javascript function.

Comment: Why can you not just enclose it in form tags within the header? I see what you are doing here though, but i don't think it's neccessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.getElementById`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/traversing-the-dom/) — but it [should be in a form](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Comment: So? You don't need it to be in a form to use getElementById, that's why I said to use getElementById. Having a text input without a form means it isn't going to work unless JavaScript is available, which is why I said it **should** be in a form.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery then simply use `$("#textboxid")` to access the textbox